# If some headphones have "Bluetooth 4.2", and my computer has "Bluetooth 4.0", will they work?

Tags: bluetooth, compatibility, headphones, macbook-air

I have looked up the specs for my family member's computer and my new headphones.

The computer has Bluetooth "4.0".

The headphones state Bluetooth "4.2".

Will they work together? If so, what's the downside of those extra two minor versions that are lacking in the computer's Bluetooth hardware?

Answer (score 1):

#### Will they work together?

Yes, but the low energy feature might not be available

> Bluetooth 4.2 extends the functionality of 4.0 by introducing a new low energy feature.
>
> Bluetooth 4.2 will be backward compatible with Bluetooth 4.0 and 4.1 devices, but the low energy feature might not be available.

Source [Question - Does bluetooth 4.0 adapter work for V4.2 bluetooth headphones? | Tom's Hardware Forum](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/does-bluetooth-4-0-adapter-work-for-v4-2-bluetooth-headphones.3486396/)

See [Is Bluetooth 4.2 compatible with 4.0? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719474/is-bluetooth-4-2-compatible-with-4-0) for a more detailed discussion.